# JQuery clone div element with few lines of html inside it and after that hide and show cloned div's some lines

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, clone, show-hide

Please, tell me someone why I can't hide and show the new cloned items?

Here is the codes:

HTML:

```
<div id="adding_copy_part" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <label for="title">Brewer Type:</label>
        <br />
        <select id="brewer_type" name="brewer_type1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
            <option value="Tea">Tea</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="brewer_type_select" id="coffee_brewer_select_div" style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;">
        <label for="title">Brewer:</label>
        <br />
        <select name="coffee_brewer1">
            <option value="">coffee1</option>
            <option value="Coffee">coffee2</option>
            <option value="Tea">coffee3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="brewer_type_select" id="tea_brewer_select_div" style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;">
        <label for="title">Brewer:</label>
        <br />
        <select name="tea_brewer1">
            <option value="">tea1</option>
            <option value="Coffee">tea2</option>
            <option value="Tea">tea3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;">
        <label for="title">Ordered Brewer Amount (pcs):</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="ordered_amount1" id="ordered_amount"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="add_fields_button"> <a style="cursor: pointer;">+ Add</a>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.brewer_type_select').hide();

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("select#brewer_type").change(function () {
        $('.brewer_type_select').hide();
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            /*$('div#add_fields_button a').after($(this).val().toLowerCase());*/
            $('#' + $(this).val().toLowerCase() + '_brewer_select_div').show();
        }
    });

    $('div#add_fields_button a').click(function () {
        $test_location = $('div#adding_copy_part').last().children().first().children().last();
        $test_location.css("background-color", "green");
        /*$(this).before($(this).parent().prev().clone());*/
        $(this).parent().prev().after($(this).parent().prev().clone(true));
        $test_location = $('div#adding_copy_part').last().children().first().children().last();
        $test_location.css("background-color", "blue");


        $(this).before('<br /> class: ' + $test_location.attr('class') + ' || id: ' + $test_location.attr('id') + ' //end.');
        $(this).parent().prev().children().each(function () {
            $(this).find('input').each(function () {
                $(this).val('');
            })
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yuRk8/

The idea, what You should do:

1. Choose brewer type to see how the function is working;
2. push on text "+ Add" to add new selection;
3. Change the "brewer type" selector for the new cloned item.
4. a)Why it doesn't hiding and showing; b) why the cloned things functionality works on the first selectors?

I can't get smart with this thing.. And even can feel that answer will be so simple that The only thing I will need to do is go to sleep ^_^

P.S. I have changed a lot of things and tried to get this done, but I don't have any more new ideas. Thanks for the help, guys! ;)

Comment: Please don't try to get around SO's rule that jsfiddle links have to be accompanied by the code.

Comment: First of all, the `.hide()` at the beginning should be inside the `ready` function.

Comment: When you clone the elements, you're creating duplicate IDs. IDs are required to be unique. You should use classes for repeated elements.

Comment: id should of unique, so since you are cloning the elements don't use id - use class instead - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vxy2D/1/

Comment: So You're telling me that all problem was only in the fact that I used IDs not Classes for the cloned things? :^)